# Installation of tensorflow terminated on RStudio Cloud

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, targets-r-package

Similarly to posts [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/persistent-python-environment-for-rstudio-cloud-projects/52350) and [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/trouble-setting-up-tensorflow-on-rstudio-cloud/52349), I am having more trouble when I try to install TensorFlow in a new RStudio Cloud project. I know I need to set up both Miniconda and a virtual environment locally in `/cloud/project/` so the Python dependencies stay with copies of the cloud project. Previous versions of the following setup script worked.

```r
install.packages(c("keras", "rstudioapi", "tensorflow"))
lines <- c(
  paste0("RETICULATE_CONDA=", file.path(getwd(), "miniconda", "bin", "conda")),
  paste0("RETICULATE_PYTHON=", file.path(getwd(), "miniconda", "bin", "python")),
  paste0("WORKON_HOME=", file.path(getwd(), "virtualenvs"))
)
writeLines(lines, ".Renviron")
rstudioapi::restartSession()
reticulate::install_miniconda("miniconda")
reticulate::virtualenv_create(
  envname = "r-tensorflow",
  python = Sys.getenv("RETICULATE_PYTHON")
)
keras::install_keras(
  method = "virtualenv",
  conda = Sys.getenv("RETICULATE_CONDA"),
  envname = "r-tensorflow"
)
```

But I get an error on Cloud when I try to install Python's TensorFlow and Keras:

```r
keras::install_keras(
+   method = "virtualenv",
+   conda = Sys.getenv("RETICULATE_CONDA"),
+   envname = "r-tensorflow"
+ )
Using virtual environment 'r-tensorflow' ...
Collecting tensorflow==2.2.0
  Downloading tensorflow-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (516.3 MB)
Killed
Error: Error installing package(s): 'tensorflow==2.2.0', 'keras', 'tensorflow-hub', 'h5py', 'pyyaml==3.12', 'requests', 'Pillow', 'scipy'
```

The same script on my local Ubuntu machine appears to succeed, but it ignores my local virtual environment even though I set `WORKON_HOME`.

```r
> tensorflow::tf_config()
Installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
 /home/landau/projects/targets-tutorial/miniconda/bin/python3.8

You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.
```

Example project that uses this general approach: https://github.com/wlandau/targets-keras.

Comment: The local installation error turned out to be an instance of https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues/426, which I solved by installing the development version of reticulate. But the original error on Cloud remains.